# file_put_contents with ampersand "&"

Tags: php, jquery

I want to copy a file from a remote server to a local server via php. I'm not sure of the "best" approach to do this so I've tried a few different ways to accomplish this but I'm hitting roadblocks with those methods.

So I came up with a method using JSONP to (A) call the remote server and get the contents of the .php file and pass it back to the local server for the local script to then (B) call to a local php script and use file_put_contents to write the content to the local server.

All works fine UNTIL an ampersand is reached. The file write stops there.

---

Edit to show data coming back.

```
if ($mysqlErrorConnectServer || $mysqlErrorConnectDb || $mysqlErrorConfigTableMissing) {
    $errorMsg .= '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"'
                  . '"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'
                  . '<head>'
                  . '<title>Example website &copy; - Example description of example site</title>'
                  . '<style type="text/css">'
```

So if you look at the code coming back... there is a "&copy" which needs to be there to display the copyright symbol on the page... but it stops the file_put_contents from writing the rest of the file.

Comment: because the code I have now is a mess from trying different things. Would cause more confusion than anything.

Comment: Then fix your code first, we're not here to clean your mess by widely guessing around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from previous response to answer my own question.

Here's the answer to the problem. :) Knew it would be something simple I had not run across yet. Before sending the data to the local write script (after receiving it back from the remote), I simply call encodeURIComponent() to my returned response and send it on to the local script to write.

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you'll need to encode the file on the remote server with `htmlspecialchars()`, and decode it when receiving it on the local end with `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

A better alternative might be to [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) the file on the remote server, however, and [`bas64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) it on the local receiving server.

Comment: It's not the data transfer that is the issue... it's the actual writing once I receive that data back from the remote server. The data coming back is PERFECT... then I go to write that data to my local copy but when an ampersand is reached... it stops file_put_contents from writing any further.

Part of the script data coming back includes the html code for copyright and when that & in " &copy; "  is reached... it stops writing.

Comment: @Lostinthesauce You should probably view the source in a hex editor or something to look for a non-printable character that could be tripping up the file write :/

Comment: file_put_contents('testing.php','<?php echo "Testing this function &copy;" ?>');

Well.. I tested this instead of the contents coming back... and this actually writes to the file. I'm so confused.

Comment: Since I can't answer my own question........ here's the answer to the problem. :) Knew it would be something simple I had not run across yet. 

Before sending the data to the local write script (after receiving it back from the remote), I simply call **encodeURIComponent()** to my returned response and send it on to the local script to write. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Lostinthesauce You can answer your own question, and doing so is encouraged, since it helps the site build as a knowledge base. You may even get a badge or two if you accept your own answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use PHP for this?

```
<?php
$file_contents = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
$handle        = fopen('new-file.html', 'w');
frwite($handle, $file_contents, strlen($file_contents));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Docs for `file_get_contents()`: http://php.net/file_get_contents

The way you're doing it with AJAX is another transfer of the data, you should get it strait from PHP if you can. Your server will have a known good internet connection, however the user may have a bad internet connection and you are asking the user to both download and upload the information.

Comment: Php can't check the REMOTE server against the LOCAL server and see if the two scripts match or don't match. As far as I know, the only way to do this is to JSONP call to the REMOTE server (passing the local file hash in the process) and checking the REMOTE hash against the LOCAL hash. If they don't match... pass me the contents of the REMOTE file so that I can then write the contents to the LOCAL file.

Comment: PHP can get the contents of remote documents, the first example on the PHP documentation for `file_get_contents()` is how to get "the source of the homepage of a website" (it uses the `http://` protocol): http://php.net/file_get_contents. I don't mean to argue here, I'm just wondering what behavior `file_get_contents()` exhibits that doesn't do what you want. I believe it gives the output after the remote server has parsed it's server-side code, do you want the actual PHP code from the remote server?

Comment: I'm don't take it you're arguing... I appreciate ANY input as this is all somewhat confusing to me too. I'm not trying to get the "end result" of the page... I'm trying to get the "exact coding" of the .php file itself. The way to accomplish this is (1) Find out first if the files are different (2) get the contents of the remote file (3) write the contents to the local file. Since the remote file using methods to ensure only the local server is calling it.. I have to call a script on that server to get the info etc then send it back to me.